# PHP Excel issue with style/fill from array

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've created a perfectly working spreadsheet-generating script with phpspreadsheet but because our server is behind on its PHP version, I"m having to modify it for PHPExcel.

I've finally fixed the script and it generates the spreadseheet correctly except for one issue:

One of my style arrays is not applying. I get no error when I execute the script, but instead of showing a gradient with the correct color, it just shows a defualt black/grey/white gradient. I've fixed the syntax to match the PHPExcel documentation but still no luck.

Is there something I'm missing here?

This is the array:

```
            $styleArray4 = array(
                'font' => array(
                    'bold' => true,
                    //'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF7133'),
                ),
                'alignment' => array(
                    'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT,
                ),
                'borders' => array(
                    'top' => array(
                        'borderStyle' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                    ),
                ),
                'fill' => array(
                    'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                    'rotation' => 90,
                    'startColor' => array(
                        'argb' => 'FF7133',
                    ),
                    'endColor' => array(
                        'argb' => 'FF7133',
                    ),
                ),
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `argb` for start and end colours, then you need to provide an [argb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) value, with rgb ***and*** the alpha opacity/transparency value, not just an [rgb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space) value.

Alternatively, provide an `rgb` value, but use `rgb` as the key rather than `argb`